# Does anyone know of a Python equivalent of FMPP?

Tags: python, preprocessor, template-engine, freemarker, fmpp

Does anyone know of a Python equivalent for [FMPP](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/) the text file preprocessor?

Follow up: I am reading the docs and looking at the examples for the suggestions given. Just to expand. My usage of FMPP is to read in a data file (csv) and use multiple templates depending on that data to create multi page reports in html all linked to a main index.

Comment: don't make such questions a community wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me add [Mako](http://makotemplates.org) Fine fast tool (and it even uses ${var} syntax).

Note: Mako, Jinja and Cheetah are *textual* languages (they process and generate text). I'd order them Mako > Jinja > Cheetah (in term of features and readability), but people's preferences vary.

Kid and it's successor [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/) are HTML/XML aware attribute languages (`<div py:if="variable"> ... </div>` etc ). That's completely different methodology - and tools suitable for HTML or XML only.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Mako it seems to have everything I need.

Answer (score 2):

Python has lots of templating engines. It depends on your exact needs.

[Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) is a good one, for example. [Kid](http://www.kid-templating.org/) is another.

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/) a try. I've used it before with some success.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what FMPP does, but from a quick glance it seems like a template language.

[Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) is an excellent template system for python.

sample:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in list %}
    <li> {{ item.title }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% if user.is_admin() %}
    <a href="./edit">Edit this page</a>
{% endif %}
```